# Using Date variables as parameters in ADF

Tags: sql, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I want to retrieve only last 3 months of data from a stored procedure that I am using.

This is the variable expression that I am using currently to pass the parameter. However it only fetches data of Oct 2021. But I want all previous 3 months. Like Oct, Nov and Dec.

@formatDateTime(addToTime(convertTimeZone(utcnow(),'UTC','New Zealand Standard Time'),-3,'Month'),'MMM yyyy')

Here are some images for more detail.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your stored procedure capable of returning data for more than one month? This appears to be an issue with your stored pric, nothing to do with ADF

Comment: This stored proc was written by someone else in another team. What they told me was I can pass parameter like this to find multiple months. For example: 'Nov 2021, Dec 2021, Jan 2021' ... sure can do in sql and its not dynamic. How can I make something like this work in ADF?

Comment: Well you don't have a comma seperated list of months there do you? How is it meant to know you want Nov if you don't have it? What is the format of this parameter? What value is your current parameter?

Comment: This parameter is a string format as per the screenshots. The orginal parameter in the stored proc is also a string format. I am not sure what you mean by "you don't have a comma separated list of months there do you?" I have a column called AccountingPeriods in the table with the list that says Months like this "Nov 2021, Dec 2021 and so on... All I want is to get last 3 months off of that list at any given time.

Comment: The parameter "AccountingPeriod" should look at the column I mentioned above, and it does. That's why I ended up with Oct 2021 data with the expression I used in my original post.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are correctly passing in `'Oct 21'` but you need to pass in `'Oct 2021, Nov 2021, Dec 2021, Jan 2021'`.

Comment: yes, I get Oct 2021 results if I pass this expression @formatDateTime(addToTime(convertTimeZone(utcnow(),'UTC','New Zealand Standard Time'),-3,'Month'),'MMM yyyy'). But I want results of all 3 months (which is oct nov dec ) not just the 3rd month from now.

Comment: In the original question you said "last 3 months". Will this list of monthds get bigger over time? i.e. you actually want months to date? I actually recommend that your stored proc developer change his proc to accept start and end months, not a list of months. Even better, change his proc to accept a "MTD" parameter and do all the work in the proc. ADF is not really suited to this.

Comment: I tried this expression @concat('''',formatDateTime(addToTime(convertTimeZone(utcnow(),

'UTC','New Zealand Standard Time'),0,'Month'),'MMM yyyy'),

'''',',','''',

formatDateTime(addToTime(convertTimeZone(utcnow(),

'UTC','New Zealand Standard Time'),-1,'Month'),'MMM yyyy'),

'''',',','''',

formatDateTime(addToTime(convertTimeZone(utcnow(),

'UTC','New Zealand Standard Time'),-2,'Month'),'MMM yyyy'),

'''',',','''',

formatDateTime(addToTime(convertTimeZone(utcnow(),

'UTC','New Zealand Standard Time'),-3,'Month'),'MMM yyyy'),''''). It works for me. Gives me last 3 month

Comment: Great. Do you want to post that as an answer. Then you can mark it as answered. Later on you can work out whether you want 3 or 4 months.

Comment: Yeah it doesnt matter whether its 3 months or 4, as far as we have a logic to work with. Thank you for your input. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@concat('''',formatDateTime(addToTime(convertTimeZone(utcnow(),

'UTC','New Zealand Standard Time'),0,'Month'),'MMM yyyy'),

'''',',','''',

formatDateTime(addToTime(convertTimeZone(utcnow(),

'UTC','New Zealand Standard Time'),-1,'Month'),'MMM yyyy'),

'''',',','''',

formatDateTime(addToTime(convertTimeZone(utcnow(),

'UTC','New Zealand Standard Time'),-2,'Month'),'MMM yyyy'),

'''',',','''',

formatDateTime(addToTime(convertTimeZone(utcnow(),

'UTC','New Zealand Standard Time'),-3,'Month'),'MMM yyyy'),'''')
```

[image]

Comment: Just be aware that if you want a true month to date, every month you have to come in and literally alter this source code.

Comment: Why would I need to alter it if it’s giving me 3 or 4 months worth of data from my current date?

Comment: If you only ever want 3 months or only ever want 4 months it's fine. If you want 5 months (as in if you are doing a month to date).... you need to go edit your code every month  and add another chunk in. I guess you are only interested in rolling months.